# Account Linking in Dialogflow Integrations (DialogflowES)

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to determine how to accomplish the following with the Dialogflow ES Facebook Messenger & Telegram integrations. Having looked extensively at Dialogflow ES documentation, there doesn't seem to be any information outside Actions on Google which I don't think can work in other integrations?

1. When a user opens the bot via Facebook Messenger or Telegram for the first time.
2. They click a FB/Telegram button that has an HREF link to my login page.
3. Once authenticated on my login page, they are redirected back to the Dialogflow bot in Facebook Messenger or Telegram, Dialogflow knows who the user is (via whichever ID is best here), and has an auth token which is passed to my backend in each subsequent fulfillment.
4. Once the auth token is expired, the user is asked by the bot to login once again and the button with HREF link appears again prompting to re-authenticate.

Ideally, the user's Facebook account or Telegram account could be used for creating, also achieving the result as above in 3.